# Pygame Error Not Showing Scaled Image

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite

So i am trying to draw a simple image of a torch in Pygame. But the problem is this sprite and all of my other sprites are around 10x10. So i was using scale to draw it experimentally like this:

```
import pygame, sys
class sprites:
    class torch(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, image_file, location):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, ((100, 100)))
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
width, height = window.get_size()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
window.fill([0, 0, 0])
sprites.torch("torch.png", (50, 50))
pygame.display.flip()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            sys.exit()
```

I am new to pygame so I am not sure what im doing wrong. Another solution to this problem would be if I could set the resolution to like 100x100 but the size to like 500x500
thanks in advance guys!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/38cy7a15jynes7c/torch.png

Ok, so according to the comments I didnt draw the sprite, then how do i? like i said, im completely new, sorry.

Comment: Also, you never draw the sprite to the window (or add it to a group or do anything else with it).

Comment: alright, sorry for seeming completely stupid, but im COMPLETELY new to pygame. Can you write a fix for this program? what functions do i use to draw the sprite? How could I scale it up?

Comment: @abarnert no. I want it to take up 100x100. i guess i took location too literally. Transparent? Yes they would appear transparent against black but they are not ACTUALLY transparent. not that it makes a difference

Comment: so are you saying that would draw the size ratio? im not sure what that arguement is actually doing.

Comment: OK, the 50x50 thing is my fault; I wasn't paying attention. You're loading the 3x5 image at its default size and scaling it up to 100x100, which should be horribly ugly, but perfectly visible. So I'll delete my first comment.

Comment: ok, but when i run the script i just get a black screen

Comment: Yeah, that's the other problem. If you don't draw anything, nothing gets drawn. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like your problem isn't that the scaling up is failing, but that the code isn't actually displaying your sprite (scaled-up or otherwise) anywhere.

If so, that's because you never tell pygame to do so. Just creating a sprite doesn't actually draw it.

You really should work through the tutorials and look over a few sample programs rather than try to figure out what is and isn't necessary and when and in what order just from the reference docs.

The basic idea is that you put your `Sprite` objects into `Group` objects, and then somewhere inside your event loop or framerate loop, you call the `draw` method on each `Group`, passing it your `window`. This is explained in the overview for [`pygame.sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite).

In your program, since you never actually update anything, but just render a single static display and then `flip` it and wait forever for a keypress, you should be able to just `draw` once:

```
thetorch = sprites.torch("torch.png", (50, 50))
everything = pygame.sprite.Group()
everything.add(thetorch)
everything.draw(window)
pygame.display.flip()
```

In many types of game, it can make sense to have static objects like this `add` themselves to a `Group` in their constructor or vice-versa, and in some games even to make a special group for static objects that `draw` themselves on construction. Although that's not very common. Again, look through the examples. If you go to the [`draw`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) docs and click "Search examples", it'll give you 50 sample programs that use that method, and you can get an idea of how they're organized. But first, go through the really basic examples in the [tutorials](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials).

Comment: thetorch.draw(window)AttributeError: 'torch' object has no attribute 'draw'

Comment: Oh, right, they took out individual `Sprite` drawing a long time ago; the idea is that you add the `Sprites` to a `Group`, then call `draw` on that. Let me update the answer.

Comment: ive learned a load from this about pygame, and i can continue, THANKS!!